# Contacts Sync problem in Android 4.4.2

Tags: sync, google

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S4 with 4.4.2 Kitkat version. Currently my phone is showing that all the contacts (phone numbers) are in sync with my Gmail account, however when I check in Gmail Contacts, I could not find even a single contact synced. 
I also checked whether the sync is enabled properly or not, but it is "checked and enabled".

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Note: All other stuff like photos, calendars, are properly synced and reflected in my Gmail.

Comment: How/Where did you check for the "sync" status? In the System Settings or in the "Contacts" app or whatever the name of the specific app.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the contacts are added to your Google account, but they are not in the "My Contacts" section but rather the "Other Contacts" section.

If you go to [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com), on the left sidebar is "My Contacts" with groups underneath. At the very bottom, just above "Import Contacts" and "New Group" is a section called "[Other Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/#contacts/group/26ae/Other+Contacts)".

These contacts are usually auto-added from Gmail, but they can also be contacts added from your phone that weren't synced quite right. Try looking in there for your contacts. If they are there, you can select all and add to "My Contacts".